# unexpected echo while displaying Element in cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I was trying to add Element in cakephp template page.

Documentation about Element in cakephp 3.0 says echo must be used.

```
echo $this->element('helloworld');
```

I follow documentation, but my website returns this error.

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)
```

When I don't use echo, it works fine. I tried directly:

```
$this->element('helloworld');
```

someone have any explanation about this error ? and where is my error ?

Answer (score 2):

if you are doing this `<?= $this->element('helloworld'); ?>` then you don't need `echo`. However, if you are doing this `<?php echo $this->element('helloworld');`, then you need `echo`.

The difference is whether you are using php's echo short syntax. `<?=` vs `<?php echo` and it has nothing to do directly with CakePHP. It is just PHP... More info here: http://php.net/echo

Answer (score 0):

in view of cakephp 3.0 elements will be directly included.
no need to use neither echo nor cakephp echoing syntax